# Finding the value of bands ratio in Sentinel 2

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I want to use the following algorithm:

[image]

So I should find the value of r first. Which is B5/B4 (bands are from Sentinel 2 L2A product). But I don't know how to find its value. First, I choose an image from Sentinel 2 L2A then,

```
var r = image.expression(
'B5/B4',{
'B5': image.select('B5'),
'B4': image.select('B4')
}
);
print(r);
```

I wrote the above script but I couldn't get the value with print.

How can I find the value of *r* so that I can proceed the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will (obviously) be different values at different locations. Add `r` to the map, using `Map.addLayer()`, select the [`Inspector`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/playground#inspector-tab) tab on the right hand side, then click on the location on the map where you want the value.

```
var r = ee.Image().expression(
  'B5/B4', {
    'B5': image.select('B5'),
    'B4': image.select('B4')
  }
)
var phi = r.clamp(0.75, 1.15)
var w = ee.Image().expression(
  '(phi - 0.75)/(1.15 - 0.75)', {phi: phi}
)

Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'B4,B3,B2', min: 0, max: 3000}, 'rgb')
Map.addLayer(phi, {min: 0.75, max: 1.15}, 'phi')
Map.addLayer(w, {min: 0, max: 1}, 'w')
```